# sql prepend entries

Tags: sql

I have some entries that are inconstant, they should be prepended by the same string.

some have numbers and other have the dollar sign and the number

so I have a syntax that finds all the entries which do not have the dollar sign

```
WHERE [mydata] not like '$%'
```

how do I add the string before each entry?

Comment: Are you asking how to add a dollar sign to all records on select or just doing a mass update?

Comment: mass update, the dollar sign is an example

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
update table set mydata = '$' + mydata where [mydata] not like '$%'
```

The + only works in SQLServer; you may need to use the `concatenate` function otherwise.

Answer (score 1):

If you are looking for just a select statement to return the value with a $, this will work:

```
Select '$' + field
from [table]
where field not like '$%'
```

You can run it as a case statement had you wanted both records that have a $ and those without to be returned with the $

```
Select case when left(field,1) = '$' then '' else '$' end + field
from [table]
where field not like '$%'
```

edit: Might need to convert the 'field' into a varchar for the + to work, you'll get a syntax error if the field is an int (but you have the $ spuradically in the field, so I assumed it's a varchar